# Get Parent Fragment return Wrong fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I have this nested fragment:

`-> = host`

`MainActivity` -> `Fragment A` -> `Fragment B` -> `Fragment C`

but when i'm trying to `getParentFragment()` from `Fragment C` , i'm getting `Fragment A` instead of `Fragment B`. I will be very thankful if someone can explain this and show me the solution.

this is how i call getParentFragment from fragment C

```
FragmentB mContext = (FragmentB) getParentFragment();
```

Comment: How did you add your fragmentA, fragmentB, fragmentC respectively?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

In the Fragment B you have to use: getChildFragmentManager() when you create the Fragment C

Comment: Solved my problem of FragmentB's being placed in very first instance of FragmentA, instead of subsequent ones too. Thanks!